# PyQt changing specific button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been looking through answers for a while but couldn't find a solution to my problem. I recently started playing around with PyQt and trying to code out couple of ideas, one of which was to have a couple of buttons with some text on them and when a button is clicked, its text would change color. Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QMainWindow,
    QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt

class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Battleship"
        self.left = 50
        self.top = 50
        self.width = 750
        self.height = 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        stylesheet = """QPushButton {background: #EEE; color: #11}
                    !QPushButton {background: #555; color: #EEE}"""
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        self.grid()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.box)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def grid(self):
        self.box = QGroupBox()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.box.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button1 = QPushButton('X', self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton('X', self)
        self.button3 = QPushButton('X', self)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pick)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.pick)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.pick)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button3)

    def pick(self):
        # turn 'X' from black to red ONLY on the clicked button
        # while leaving the others untouched 
        pass

#---------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What does the 'pick' function have to look like in order to do this? To clarify: I don't want to make three individual functions, one for each button (as it would be very impractical for a larger number of buttons), but a single function which would work with any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [`sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) method returns us the object that emits the signal, in your case the button will be pressed:

```
def pick(self):
    # turn 'X' from black to red ONLY on the clicked button
    # while leaving the others untouched 
    btn = self.sender()
    btn.setStyleSheet("color: red")
```